# Recovering chmod's execute permission

Tags: unix, chmod

This was an interview question. Let's say you revoked the execute permission of *chmod* binary -- i.e., you cannot run "chmod u+x chmod" because chmod doesn't have +x. Without obtaining a copy of chmod's binary file outside of the local file system, how can you recover chmod's execute permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `install`:

```
install -m +rx /bin/chmod /tmp/chmod
/tmp/chmod 755 /bin/chmod # or just copy it back.
```

2) Use busybox's chmod

```
/bin/busybox chmod 755 /bin/chmod
```

3) Use `cp` and `cat` (`dd` can work as well):

```
cp -a /bin/sh /tmp/chmod
cat /bin/chmod > /tmp/chmod
/tmp/chmod 755 /bin/chmod
```

Comment: Also this command works: `perl -e 'chmod 0777, "foobar.file"'`